# Can an object have an instantaneous velocity if it has zero acceleration?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, acceleration, velocity

Can an object have an instantaneous velocity if it has zero acceleration?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Acceleration is change in velocity; when acceleration is zero, the velocity is constant, but not necessarily zero.

Comment: Thank You for your response, that was very helpful. What can be an example of this? just to have a better understanding.

Comment: Even if an object's velocity is constant and zero, it still has an instantaneous velocity at all time points. It's just zero.

Comment: Example: When you drive your car at 60 km/h, but have your foot on the pedal just enough so that you stay at 60 km/h. Then you don't accelerate, but your velocity is still 60 km/h.